# How to update Index settings after index creation in spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am writting spring-boot application using spring-data-elasticsearch. I have an entity class which automatically creates index in elasticsearch. But I want to define and set an analyzer to a field.

I am expecting something like callback to support this. Now index is getting created using the @Document

```
@Document(indexName = "products", shards = 1, versionType = VersionType.INTERNAL, createIndex = true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either disable automatic index creation, and do the index creation by yourself using the `IndexOperations.create(Document settings)` method. The `Document`.

Or you provide the settings in a json file on the classpath and refer to it with the `@Setting` annotation. As a reference check this [test code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/4.2.0-M2/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repositories/setting/dynamic/DynamicSettingAndMappingEntityRepositoryTests.java#L194-L226)

Comment: What if we make changes in the settings after it is created in the createIndex=true mode? Will those changes reflect in the index settings?

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch's `IndexOperations` currently does not support updating the index settings.

Comment: I think then its always better to create index manually